# Duda para escoger framework para desarrollo web en python

Tags: python, django, web, flask

soy novato en el desarrollo de aplicaciones web, y me gustaría poder diseñar un pequeño proyecto que incluya que el cliente pueda ver un streaming de una cam, chatear con el servidor y subir archivos como principal características, y que depende del tipo de usuario pueda conectarse con X personas o solo con el servidor por ejemplo.
Como conozco algo las bases de python tenia pensado intentar entre flask o django, pero no soy capaz de decidir bien que framework usar, me gustaría saber si podéis ayudarme a decidir o decirme que alternativa usaríais y porque para poder aclararme por que camino tomar.
Gracias por si tiempo

Comment: Hola. SO no es un buen lugar para preguntar recomendaciones, u otras cosas basadas en opiniones. Será mejor que busques en otro lado.

Comment: Y donde puedo ir a buscar especificamente?

Answer (score 1):

Lo comento aqui por que no tengo suficientes puntos para hacer un comentario. Pero pues tu pregunta facilmente se puede resolver escribiendola en google y ver en paginas como [esta](https://www.monocubed.com/top-python-frameworks/) o en el grupo de [Python](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/) de reddit o similar.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones generalmente quedan cerradas pues no se ajustan a [ask], es mejor evitar responderlas